# Sending basic email notifications to self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

All I want to do is send notification emails to myself. I do not need a template at the moment. I am currently getting the error:

`Template Missing`

```
Missing template home/send_mail, application/send_mail with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/bli1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/Users/bli1/Development/RoR/Boothie/app/views" * "/Users/bli1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta4/app/views"
```

Route:

`match '/send_mail', to: "home#send_mail", via: "get"`

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def send_mail
    ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => "me@example.com", :to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "Contact request", :body => "test").deliver
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel the render using:

```
 def send_mail
    ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => "me@example.com", :to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "Contact request", :body => "test").deliver
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Comment: That got rid of the error thanks! But not sure if the email sent. Still waiting =/

Comment: try checking your SMTP log